# Import historical Metatrader CSV data to Python with Pandas library (date/time parsing)

Tags: python, parsing, csv, pandas, metatrader4

I have some CSV data like

```
2011.12.08,22:45,1.33434,1.33465,1.33415,1.33419,265
2011.12.08,23:00,1.33419,1.33542,1.33419,1.33472,391
2011.12.08,23:15,1.33470,1.33483,1.33383,1.33411,420
2011.12.08,23:30,1.33413,1.33451,1.33389,1.33400,285
```

coming from Metatrader 4 in a file named EURUSD15.csv

I would like to import this file with Python using Pandas library and read_csv function...

So I did this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pandas import *
df = read_csv('data/EURUSD15.csv', header=None)
df.columns = ['Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
print(df)
```

I would like now to have date/time parsed...

so I changed

```
df = read_csv('data/EURUSD15.csv', header=None)
```

to

```
df = read_csv('data/EURUSD15.csv', header=None, parse_dates=[[1, 2]])
```

But I get this error message

> ```
> Exception: Length mismatch (7 vs 6)
> ```

How can I parse date and time columns and have the 2 columns considered as 1 "datetime" column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns are zero indexed, so you need to do **`parse_dates=[[0,1]]`**
This is on latest version of pandas but should work with 0.8.0+:

```
In [74]: data = """\
2011.12.08,22:45,1.33434,1.33465,1.33415,1.33419,265
2011.12.08,23:00,1.33419,1.33542,1.33419,1.33472,391
2011.12.08,23:15,1.33470,1.33483,1.33383,1.33411,420
2011.12.08,23:30,1.33413,1.33451,1.33389,1.33400,285
"""

In [75]: pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), 
                     names=['Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'], 
                     index_col='Date_Time', parse_dates=[[0, 1]])
Out[75]: 
                        Open     High      Low    Close  Volume
Date_Time                                                      
2011-12-08 22:45:00  1.33434  1.33465  1.33415  1.33419     265
2011-12-08 23:00:00  1.33419  1.33542  1.33419  1.33472     391
2011-12-08 23:15:00  1.33470  1.33483  1.33383  1.33411     420
2011-12-08 23:30:00  1.33413  1.33451  1.33389  1.33400     285
```

Note the `index_col=0` will also work. Complex date parsing prepends resulting columns so parse_dates will refer to pre-date processing column indices (i.e., 0 is Date and 1 is Time) and `index_col` refers to post-date processing column indices. Thus, using column names are recommended since it allows you to not have to think about pre-vs-post processing columns indices.

Answer (score 0):

parse_dates doesn't take the index values.

Try something like:

```
pd.read_csv('data/EURUSD15.csv',  parse_dates = [['YYYY.MM.DD', 'HH:MM']], index_col = 0, 
        date_parser=parse)
```

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work !
    df = read_csv('data/EURUSD15.csv', header=None, parse_dates=[0])
works for the first column and
    df = read_csv('data/EURUSD15.csv', header=None, parse_dates=[1])
works for the second column
but not
 df = read_csv('data/EURUSD15.csv', header=None, parse_dates=[[0, 1]])

Comment: when I try your code
 df = read_csv('data/EURUSD15.csv', header=None, parse_dates = [['YYYY.MM.DD', 'HH:MM']], index_col = 0, date_parser=parse)
I get this error message
 NameError: name 'parse' is not defined
So I tryed
 df = read_csv('data/EURUSD15.csv', header=None, parse_dates = [['YYYY.MM.DD', 'HH:MM']], index_col = 0, date_parser=True)
and get this error message
 ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (15719) into shape (0)

Answer (score 0):

```
parse = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
df = pd.read_csv('data/EURUSD15.csv', parse_dates=[[0, 1]], date_parser=parse, index_col=[0],   header=None)
keys = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close','Volume']
df.columns = [x for x in keys]
```

Comment: If you could add some explanations to your answer it would improve it a lot!

Answer (score 0):

easier method is using the drag and drop solution called [pytrader](https://github.com/TheSnowGuru/PyTrader-python-mt4-mt5-trading-api-connector-drag-n-drop), check it out on github.

Comment: Please include MWE using pytrader.